# Como manter um projeto web em sincronização com servidor remoto?

Tags: aplicação-web, servidor

Gostaria de saber as melhores práticas de manter um projeto web atualizado em um servidor remoto. Estou iniciando um projeto web em que eu preciso mantê-lo em um servidor remoto, e a partir do meu servidor local mantenho sincronizado todos os arquivos no servidor, para melhor atualização. Eu tentei manter sincronizado em um netbeans com ftp, mas as vezes não atualiza. Qual a melhor prática para isso ?

Comment: Fazia isso no Dreamweaver. Mas eu odeio Dreamweaver, então não uso mais. Sincronizo manualmente.

Comment: Meu localhost serve apenas para desenvolvimento, o apache está rodando em um servidor remoto (VPS), quero mantê-los sincronizado com o meu localhost e fazer atualizações que sejam feitas diretamente no servidor.

Comment: uma ferramenta muito fácil de utilizar é o controle de versão GIT eles tem um [tutorial completo em português](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1), ao utilizar repositórios remotos você sincroniza com um único comando, e existe integração com diversas IDEs

Answer (score 1):

Hoje em dia existem muitas soluções que nos permitem responder à sincronização de projectos remotamente e online.

Enquanto profissional sou obrigado a faze-lo de diversas formas. Neste momento um dos projetos que tenho em mãos desenvolvo com o `NETBEANS` e este dispõe de uma funcionalidade que nos permite e sem esforço gerir um projeto localmente e remotamente, sincronizando a cada passo.

É possível escolher se sincroniza quando grava o arquivo ou a cada execução do nosso projeto.

Utilizando um `IDE` como `NETBEANS` ou outros, o nosso dia a dia é muito mais fácil no que respeita a desenvolver código e a testá-lo. No fim, muito mais  produtivo.

Comment: Uso Netbeans com SVN, e configuro nas propriedades do projeto "Executar Configuração"  a conexão remota para fazer o upload do arquivo :)

Answer (score 0):

Eu faço isso com um projeto usando git, é só você ficar sincronizando com o repositório.

Se preferir faça um schedule no seu servidor para sincronizar de tempos em tempos.

Existem linguagens como o node.js que você pode configurar uma task para efetuar isso remoto também.

Answer (score 0):

Como o @chambelix disse existem muitas soluções, a que estou a usar neste momento é Sublime Text 2 + SFTP

Permite diversas opções interessantes:

- Sincronização Local > Servidor
- Sincronização Servidor > Local
- Sincronização em ambas as direcções ( nunca experimentei )
- Podes navegar listar as pastas do servidor

Depois existe um ficheiro chamado sftp-config.json que onde se encontram todas as configurações da sincronização, aí podes alterar para ver qual se adequada melhor as tuas exigências.

Contêm:

1. Informações relativas do server "host", "user", "password" (opcional,
   se não a colocares irá mostrar um prompt para a colocares)
2. Gravar antes de fazer upload
3. Ao gravar fazer automaticamente upload
4. Regex com ficheiros e directórios que não queres sincronizar, por
   defeito vem já o próprio ficheiro sftp-config.json, para não ser
   enviado para o servidor.
5. Permissões dos ficheiros e directórios

Entre outras opções, se estiveres a usar o sublime text é um must.

Vê o link abaixo

http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp (tem o mesmo tipo de licença que o sublime text